# Calculate Hamming Distance in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, mobile, hamming-distance, bitcount

I wanted to compare multiple images and retrieve the most similar image using [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). The only problem is SQLite which is the most commonly available database in mobile platform doesn't support those important function needed by hamming distance like bitcount.

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979769/calculate-hamming-distance-and-weight-in-sqlite) is posted 2 years ago, but it doesn't seem to have any workaround or does SQLite supported those function currently.

Does anyone know how to work around this problem or have a better idea on how to do image comparison in mobile platform without blowing up the CPU and storage?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you load it from DB and process it in Java? Images shouldn't be stored in DB anyway

Comment: The DB will just store the hash string of the image, not the image itself. The number is too huge to load everything on memory and do the comparison.